# Async.js "Callback was already called"; can't debug

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I am using async.js to help with validation and transformations for data imports. After moving a piece of code to it's own function I get the error "Callback was already called." from async.js. The stack trace has no useful information on debugging. The exact code works fine when I call it directly. I need to use it across multiple imports so that's why I moved to the an object containing other "transformers". They all work fine.

I've tried inserting the following code into the function to try to  debug:

```
return cb("test);
```

It runs fine and returns the error "test" to the browser if I add it to the first line of the function. Inserting it anywhere else causes the error.

The following works. If I move "return cb("error);" to the line after let query = ... it will fail with the callback error. I'm quite confused.

```
user(options = {
        select: "id",
        return: "id",
        lean: true,
    }) {
        return (value, cb) => {
            if (!value) {
                return cb(null, null);
            }

            return cb("test");

            let query = User.findOne({
                $or: [{
                        email: value.toLowerCase()
                    },
                    {
                        username: value
                    },
                ]
            }).select(options.select);

            if (options.lean) {
                query.lean();
            }

            query.exec((error, user) => {
                if (error) {
                    return cb(error);
                }

                if (!user) {
                    return cb(`user not found: ${value}`);
                }

                if (options.return == "object") {
                    cb(null, user);
                } else {
                    cb(null, user._id);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The variable "cb" is passed from an async call:

```
        async.mapValues(self.options.validators, (validators, key, cb) => {
            //Get the value that is being validated
            var value = _.get(document, key);
            var isArray = false;

            //Enforce array type
            if (!Array.isArray(validators)) {
                validators = [validators];
            }

            //Transform the value before validating it
            var transformer = _.get(self.options.transformers, key);

            //Don't run transformer if empty value
            if (!transformer || value == null) {
                transformer = (value, cb) => cb(null, value);
            }

            transformer(value, (error, newValue) => {
                //Check error
                if (error) {
                    return _cb(error);
                }

                //Set new value
                value = newValue;
                _.set(document, key, newValue);
```

Comment: I don't see where you using `async.js`.

Comment: @hoangdv The function passed as cb is the async.js callback for async.mapValues(). I'll update the post